# Download aspx pages using python in local

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer, python

I have a client ID and secret of my SharePoint.

I have some SharePoint page URLs, which I need to download them to the local using python.

It will good if I can download them as pdf, but as of now, I don't know any library which can do so.